# PyYAML ConstructError: could not determine a constructor for the tag

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

I have several classes constructed with PyYAML using Python 2.7. But only the class defined below fails with:

```
ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 
    '!ClassifyTransform'
        in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 5:
        --- !ClassifyTransform
            ^
```

The YAML string is as follows:

```
        self.yamlconfig =  dedent(u'''\
        --- !ClassifyTransform
        file_with_path: '/../../testdata/classify.csv'
        skip_header_lines: 1
        duplicates: []
        outtype: 'dataframe'
        client: 'test'
        classifycolumn: [ 
            { newcolumn: 'audit_status',
              conditions: [['', 'Status', '==', {scalar: 'F', column: None}], ['&', 'STATUS', '==', {scalar: 'C', column: None}]],
              value: [['', {scalar: 'Filled', column: None}]]
            },
            { newcolumn: 'audit_status',
              conditions: [['', 'Status', '%NA', {scalar: '', column: None}], ['&', 'STATUS', '==', {scalar: 'C', column: None}]],
              value: [['', {scalar: 'Filled - Order Missing', column: None}], ['+', {scalar: '', column: None}]]
            }
        ]
    ''')
```

I use the same pattern for the constructor as in all my other classes:

```
def transform_constructor(loader, node):
    instance = ClassifyTransform.__new__(ClassifyTransform)
    yield instance
    state = loader.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)
    instance.__init__(**state)

yaml.add_constructor(yaml_tag, transform_constructor)
```

I cannot identify what is wrong with the yamlconfig.

I discovered in experimenting I had used this import

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
```

in my class and the yaml import in my testcase, no surprise it did not work.

Comment: You don't define yaml_tag in your source. Is it really `u'!ClassifyTransform'`, or maybe something else? It is often best to make the tag a class variable on `ClassifyTransform` named `yaml_tag` and then do  `yaml.add_constructor(ClassifyTransform.yaml_tag, transform_constructor)`

Comment: When you write "I discovered in experimenting I had used this import. import ruamel.yaml as yaml. in my class and the yaml import in my testcase, no surprise it did not work."  Do you mean that you solved you problem ?

Comment: Yes is now works

Comment: @oldDave how did you solve this? Maybe add the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
pip3 install PyYAML==3.13
```

Required latest version of PyYAML. New Version support it and stable

For python 2.7 similar latest upgraded version required too.